# Problem in implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> Let $$x^2+xy+y^2=2$$
> Find $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}$

Applying $\frac{d()}{dx}$ on both sides gives $$\frac{dy}{dx}(2y+x)=-(2x+y)$$

For $x\neq -2y$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{(2x+y)}{(2y+x)}$$

Substituting $x=-2y$ in original equation gives two solutions. Let them be $(\alpha,\beta) \text{&} (\gamma,\delta)$

Now clearly we can't use above definition to calculate derivative at $x=\alpha,\gamma$

I thought that following limit can help

$$\lim_{x\to \alpha}\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(\alpha)$$

since for points near to $(\alpha,\beta)$, we can use the derivative definition we found above.

Is this correct ?

Comment: Note: instead of saying "Doing $\frac{d()}{dx}$ on both sides," you can say "Differentiating with respect to $x$ on both sides" or "Applying $\frac{d}{dx}$ to both sides".

Comment: When $x=-2y$, the curve $x^2+xy+y^2=2$ has a vertical tangent. [Hence, $dy/dx$ does not exist in this case](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j0hnmygm9w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach relies on the fact that the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a continuous function of $x$. *But* you can avoid (explicitly) taking limits by considering the reciprocal-slope $\frac{dx}{dy}$. When you implicitly differentiate with respect to $y$, you will get$^\dagger$ the reciprocal expression:
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = - \frac{2y+x}{2x+y}
$$

This is clearly equal to $0$ when $x=-2y$. In the standard coordinates, with $x$ horizontal and $y$ vertical, this means that the tangent lines at those points are vertical, i.e. the heuristic calculation
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} \mathrel{``="} \frac{1}{0} \mathrel{``="} \infty
$$
is correct.

Here's a sketch, including the two points on the ellipse where $x=-2y$, namely
$$
(x, y) = \biggl( \pm\frac{2\sqrt6}{3}, \mp\frac{\sqrt6}{3} \biggr).
$$
[image: Ellipse with vertical tangent lines.]

---

$^\dagger$ You don't have to literally go through the steps of differentiating with respect to $y$. You can just write down the reciprocal expression since by the chain rule,
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dy} = 1.
$$

Comment: Yes it's clear, the slope of normal at those points will be zero which implies slope of tangent will be undefined